# Variant of $\leq$ (less or equal)-symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am looking for a way to include a `\leq` that (to me) is less ugly. In the font I am using `\leq` simply produces a `<` with an underline, but in my handwriting the lower "arm" of the `<` would be parallel to the lower line.

To give you an impression of what I am aiming for here is a hack:

```
\newcommand{\fauxleq}{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=c]{25.5}{$\displaystyle\leqslant$}}}
```

which produces

[image: faux leq]

obviously the lines are mismatched and also the angle is way to wide to look acceptable.

So, is anyone aware of a better solution (or a font that regularly draws `\leq` in the way I am looking way to "borrow" it from)?

---

EDIT: @percusse : I don't know how to include an image in a comment. Is your point that `\fauxleq` is ugly? I know that, that's why I search for a better alternative
[image: fauxleq vs leq]

Comment: This is typographically questionable in two terms, first, this is not a less than symbol but an angle notation hence points towards downwards (it would be uglier if you use it without the underline. And second when you use it with a displaced underline it makes it italicisized in the counter clockwise and in complicated math expressions will make it pretty ugly especially with upright math fonts.

Comment: Do you know `\leqslant`?

Comment: @percusse In the context I would be using it, it cannot be confused with an angle. I want to use it for some estimations on variables, say $x \leq 2$.

Comment: @Sigur: I do, see my hack, but I want it to be closer to an equal than to a less (if that makes sense)

Comment: Try with `$1\fauxleq4$`

Comment: @percusse I edited the original post to include the image

Comment: As said @Sigur, I would use the French `\leqslant`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find this a very bad idea, but the customer's always right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\fauxleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\dofauxleq\relax}}

\newcommand{\dofauxleq}[2]{%
    \sbox0{$\mathsurround=0pt #1\leq$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd0}%
    \begin{picture}(1,0.7)
    \roundcap\roundjoin
    \put(0.1,0){\line(1,0){0.8}}
    \polyline(0.9,0.2)(0.1,0.2)(0.9,0.7)
    \end{picture}%
}

\begin{document}

$A\fauxleq B_{\fauxleq}$

$A\leq B_{\leq}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I kind of like it, at least on higher zoom levels, but using it in a larger document does not seem to be possible "Tex Capacity exceeded"

Comment: @victorolosaurus You may have `\fauxleq` in dangerous places; declare it as a robust command, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I still have problems using this a multiple number of times, but your answer is what I've been looking for, so I accepted it (sorry for delay)